# Проверить существование метода у объекта? java

Tags: java

Хочу проверить, есть ли у объекта `mail` метод `getMessage`. Как это сделать?

в PHP я это делал так:

```
method_exists(mail, 'methodName');
```

есть ли что-то подобное в Java?

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
public Sendable processMail(Sendable mail) {
    // хочу проверить, есть ли у переданного объекта метод getMessage
    try{
        mail.getClass.getMethods("getMessage", /*что здесь нужно написать?*/);
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
        // ignore
    }
}
```

ничего не получается. Не пойму, чего ему не хватает, и вообще, что не так?

Comment: Эта штука не работает потому, что в этом случае проверка идёт во время компиляции. Вам нужно использовать рефлексию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте сделать так

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

boolean hasMethod = false;
Method[] methods = mail.getClass().getMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
  if (m.getName().equals("getMessage")) {
    hasMethod = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

---

2 вариант

```
Method m = null;
try {
  m = Sendable.class.getMethod("getMessage");
  // метод есть 
} catch (Exception e) {
  // нет такого метода
}
```

Comment: Ваш код хорош для класса с 2-3 методами. И только если этот класс используется не так часто. В противном случае, производительность ляжет на дно.

Comment: У меня этот код ругается на правильность синтаксиса. Хочет второй аргумент методу getMethod

Comment: @LEQADA это вообще неправильное замечание для ускорения можно кэшировать список методов во внутренних полях (если считаете что рефлексия медленная).. хотя и класс с сотнями методов это архитектурная проблема

Метод с try { } catch { } почти всегда хуже... это логика на исключениях не забывайте об этом.

Comment: @Razzwan там в аргументах типы принимаемых параметров (т.к. в java возможны перегрузки методов и методу с одним названием могут соответствовать несколько методов с разными параметрами)

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov, вы утверждаете, что разумно каждый раз при вызове метода проходиться по массиву в поисках его?

Comment: @LEQADA это лучше чем исключение обрабатывать в общем случае.
Если есть подозрение что извлекать свойства медленно, то сделать это можно один раз для класса, благо сигнатуры не меняются.

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov, я и не говорил, чем лучше пользоваться, как и не говорил, что код нерабочий. Но, всё же, хотелось бы увидеть более полное и эффектное решение этого вопроса.

Comment: @LEQADA это довольно эффективное решение... К тоже единственное которое позволяет метод только по имени найти.

Answer (score 4):

В java так делать не принято. Принято проверять, реализует ли объект заданный (интерфейсный) тип. Быстро и надежно.

```
interface Container {
   String getMessage();
}
...
if (mail instanceof Container) {
   Container contmail=(Container) mail;
   String message=contmail.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Это, конечно, идеальное решения для случая, когда объект  `mail` под вашим контролем. А если это библиотечный объект? `instanceof` покамест не умеет в duck typing.

Comment: в любом случае, `getMessage()` в каком-то классе описан. Возможно, в нескольких классах (тогда это разные методы, с разными параметрами), тогда надо будет устраивать несколько проверок, с разными реакциями для заполнения параметров.

Comment: Ну, `getMessage` может для случая библиотечной функции вовсе не быть методом какого-либо интерфейса. Хотя, конечно, вы правы в том, что ТС, скорее всего, хочет проверить местоположение объекта в иерархии классов, а не просто бессемантичное наличие метода.

Comment: а я и не говорю об интерфейсе, я говорю о классе (интерфейс - тоже класс). В каком-то классе метод да описан, и принадлежность объекта этому классу можно проверять.

Comment: Ну, для начала, метод может быть добавлен и в анонимный объект. Это раз. А во-вторых, если вы хотите проверить наличие метода `size()` у `Collection`, `Trousers`, `NationalDebt` и кто-там-ещё-имеет-размер, вам придётся захардкодить **вообще все** базовые типы, в которых этот самый `size()` описан.

Comment: В любом случае, это решение правильное: проверки на «умение» должны делаться через интерфейс (и по возможности на этапе компиляции). Хотеться проверить наличие метода по имени, не обращая внимания на смысл, не должно.

Answer (score 2):

В javadoc все подробно [расписано](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()).

Метод `getMethods()` возвращает массив методов, и в качестве параметров ничего не принимает.